# how to read images from "Drawable" instead of "SD Card" Android

Tags: java, android, xml

i am beginner in android programing, and i created a Full Screen Image Slider app using this tutorial:

**Link:**
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

in this tutorial it reads images from Sd Card but i want to read images from drawable folder, i don't want to access images from SD Card instead access images from drawable.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I've seen, I hope it is correct:

```
private Bitmap bitmap = null;

private void createBitmap(Context context)
{
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Drawable d = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.imagename);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
 Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
```

where this refers to the context of the actual activity.

**OR**

you can just give the name of the image and then you can get the image using [`getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29),

```
getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable", getPackageName());
```

Where name will be the name of your image i.e - `"image1"`